# Grails logout button not working

Tags: grails

I am using the following code in my logout button :

```
<a id="login-control-logout" href="${createLink(controller:'LicGenerator', action:'logout')}"><i class="icon-off"></i> Logout</a></li>
```

Inside my controller, I am using the following code :

```
  def logout() {
    request.getSession().invalidate()
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate")
    response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache")
    response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0)
    redirect(uri:'/login.html')
}
```

It goes to login.html, but when I enter the username and password again, it doesn't log me back in and throws an error

```
type Status report

message /LicGenerator/j_security_check

description The requested resource (/LicGenerator/j_security_check) is not available.
```

When I refresh the browser, I got this error :

```
type Status report

message Invalid direct reference to form login page

description The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect (Invalid direct reference to form login page).
```

Also, the back button takes me to page even though I added cache control to response.

Comment: have you tried what is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9509847/secure-web-apps-in-tomcat

Comment: yeah, my web.xml is the same as mentioned in the post. I am editing the post with the login mechanism usd in web.xml. Still I am unable to figure out where to redirect my logout button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply invalidating your session for spring security is probably not advisable. As there is a SecuritySession which also has cookies. It may be better to use whats provided by spring security already.

```
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils

redirect uri: SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig.logout.filterProcessesUrl
```

Then you can configure your default login url via the config options for the spring security plugin